# Issue loading JSON in Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I've taken the Highstock intraday Apple stock price example htm file and uploaded it to my server: http://54.175.177.142/ef.html

It works nicely. This is the same as what's in the Highstock examples download, except that I've changed the .js paths to those hosted at the code.highcharts.com domain, instead of in the example folder.

Now what I'd like to do is to change the .json path from that hosted on highcharts.com:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-    intraday.json&callback=?', function (data) {
```

to my own server: `$.getJSON('http://54.175.177.142/appleData.json', function (data) {`

From here I'll change the JSON to my own data, but as a first step I'd just like to redo the highstock example.

Here's the problem, when I make this change to the `$.getJSON` call, I get a blank white page, I don't even get any javascript errors. This implementation can be seen at: http://54.175.177.142/intradayTest.htm

The JSON I'm trying to load is nearly identical to [the original](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json), except in my latest attempt to get it working, I've droped the "callback" at the very top for a "?" as this is how it loads when the JSONP parameter is added to the link (the &callback=?) in the example. I gather that I don't need the JSONP approach because I'm hosting the JSON on my own server, same domain as the html file. I'd also tried exactly replicating the JSON on a different server, with the leading "callback" and the JSONP parameter, to no avail.

My JSON is here: 
http://54.175.177.142/appledata.json

I'm thinking the JSON itself is somehow wrong. To make it, I just did a 'select all' on the original in my browser, pasted it into Notepad++ and saved it as a .json. Then I scp'ed it onto my EC2.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Here is the html code if you prefer not to go to the links:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
//'http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?'
//'http://52.0.68.76/appleData.json'
      $.getJSON('http://54.175.177.142/appleData.json', function (data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title: {
                text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
            },

            xAxis: {
                gapGridLineWidth: 0
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                buttons : [{
                    type : 'hour',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1h'
                }, {
                    type : 'day',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1D'
                }, {
                    type : 'all',
                    count : 1,
                    text : 'All'
                }],
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled : false
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                type: 'area',
                data : data,
                gapSize: 5,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },
                fillColor : {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops : [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                threshold: null
            }]
        });
    });
});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. This question is a candidate for deletion me thinks. I've fixed my problem....
I was opening appleData.json...but I was uploading the file as appledata.json, i.e. with a lowercase 'd'.

The difference between the two json files was that I had not appreciated that the callback(); that was wrapped around the JSON was a function. All I needed to do was take away this function and leave it as:

```
[
[1317888000000,372.5101,375,372.2,372.52],
 .
 .
 .
[1318607940000,421.94,422,421.8241,422]
]
```

Such a dumb error! But this is the way of things as a Noob.